# a href tag using a variable javascript within innerHTML

Tags: javascript

How do i get my innerHTML 'a' tag to use my javascript variable? It's probably a duplicate question, I apologize, I couldn't find an example with as much innerHTML as I do.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                results.innerHTML += "<a 'href=" + data[3][i] + "'>" ;
                results.innerHTML += "<li class='result'><h1>" + data[1][i] +"</h1><br><br><p>"+ data[2][i] +"</p></li></a>";
            };
```

thats what I have right now, I know it's sloppy. Before this attempt, I tried to do an innerHTML inside an innerHTML but didn't work.

Comment: I'd be less concerned about "sloppy" and more concerned about "invalid"; the markup you're generating is not valid at all.

Comment: This is why you use DOM methods like [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead of using `+=` on `innerHTML` which causes the element to be re-rendered each time and causing the browser to "fix" broken html before the next `+=`. Look in the Elements tab of the developer tools of the browser and you should see your html in a format you didnt intend

Comment: Please put your full code onto https://jsfiddle.net/ , include html.

Comment: If you want to use a loop to produce HTML as a string then build up the string in a variable and assign to `.innerHTML` *once* after the loop completes. This is much more efficient than repeatedly updating the DOM, *and* it avoids the issue Patrick described where you can't create half an element at a time. Or use `appendChild`, etc. as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this as well:

```
       var tags = function(arg) {
        return arg = document.getElementById(arg) || document.querySelector(arg);
      };
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
var data = "#";
var ind = 10; 
var cnt = 1;
var results = tags('.row');  
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    results.appendChild(ul);
for (var x = 0; x < ind; ++x) {

var txt = document.createTextNode('variable\u0020' + cnt++);
var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', data);
    a.appendChild(txt);
var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
});
```